# How to make duplicate bookmarks in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

In Firefox (Current latest version 35.0), if I save a bookmark at location X in my bookmarks tree with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, then do the same again for location Y, the bookmark at location X disappears.

How can I have duplicate bookmarks in FireFox?

Comment: hold `Ctrl` and drag that bookmark, this will create a copy i.e. duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is ok with duplicate bookmarks, it's just that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> that assumes you don't want duplicates.

Here are a few workarounds:

1. Before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, **add a `#` character to end of the URL**. This makes no difference for the interpretation of the URL but is enough for Firefox to think it's a new bookmark.
2. Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, go into the **Bookmark Manager** (menu `Bookmarks`, `Show All Bookmarks`, then copy/paste the Bookmark between folders to create a copy (dragging only moves the bookmark).

BTW Instead of duplicating bookmarks, **organize them with Tags** which are a better concept for multiple-categorization. Folders are meant to be a single structure of categorization.

Comment: I have edited your answer because 2) dragging (or Ctrl-dragging) does not work and 3) does not answer my question.

Comment: Adding `?` is valid only if there is no `?` in the URL. Otherwise `&` should be added.

Comment: @ Jan Doggen: I just tried dragging and it worked...

Comment: @gronostaj: I had tried the second `?` and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm not saying it's good URL syntax, just that sites seem to ignore it and it serves the current purpose.

Comment: If it's invalid URL (it is) then it's not guaranteed to work. Never rely on unspecified behavior. Btw, I think adding a `#` should work and is perfectly safe.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `#` instead of `?`. Thanks.

Comment: @pgr Yes, I have retested and (Ctrl-)dragging does work in general - but I have some 3000+ bookmarks in total and FireFox often cannot keep up with bookmark operations. I often have to wait, or a treelist does not update, or a new folder does not appear until I collapse/reopen a node etc.